# Sample python code for using Google books api

Tags: python, django, google-data-api, google-books

I m working on a library project where users can add books into their library. So I tried finding some sample code that will help me get started but could not find any. So I want to know how to use Google Book API to get Title,Description,Book Cover image and ISBN code of the queried book? btw I want the python code example. Eagerly await your assistance. Thank You.

Comment: Were you able to find sample code for this ?